# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.freeplane.main.osgi.Activator when building Freeplane

Tags: java, intellij-idea, freeplane

I'm running Freeplane locally on IntelliJ IDE using Java 11. After restarting the IDE and running Freeplane I now get this error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.freeplane.main.osgi.Activator`

I've restarted IntelliJ, re-pulled the code for a fresh install, uninstalled and re-installed the IDE.

The Activator file is there, but the build is still throwing an error.